# Safari version of Chrome's ability to middle-click back button?

Tags: macos, safari, extension, safari-extensions

Common scenario: You open a youtube link to a nice song to listen to. But you need to get back to browsing!

On Chrome all you do is middle-click Back (Guarantee chances are you did not know you could do this... You're welcome).

Now what I really want to know is... does there exist

- **a Safari (OS X) extension that lets me do this?**

Failing that, can someone summarize if the Safari Extensions APIs make this a reasonable thing to do? I feel like they ought to be able to give you access to the history navigation list, but we sort of do need more than just that, because you see, the newly created "Back" tab has cloned the original back/forward browser navigation stack from the original tab (which is still running undisturbed!). So it would not be a trivial extension methinks.

Comment: I've read this 5 times & I'm still not sure what you want. 'Back' is Cmd/[ so all you need to do is map that to the middle button in Safari. Presumably you have some kind of non-standard mouse, as no Apple mouse has a middle button, so an alternative might be to map it in your mouse software, which is how I do it for my Logitech.

Comment: No man, do you have Chrome? Follow my instructions

Comment: Chrome lets you "bifurcate" or clone a browsing timeline by middle clicking back to keep your current page undisturbed while letting you browse backward in a new tab.

Comment: Doesn't work here, even if I default my middle button… but I did at last figure out what you were asking... Safari equivalent is Cmd/click the back button; or Cmd/shift/click to do that & bring the new [old] tab to the front.

Comment: Dunno why it doesnt work for you, because im pretty sure it's supposed to work and has for six years: http://lifehacker.com/5585192/middle-click-browser-history-buttons-to-go-back-or-forward-in-new-tabs. Well, thanks, you actually found a partial answer! Cmd+Click on it works, the only bummer is it doesnt bring back the original history chain like Chrome does. But it's still way better than nothing.

Comment: "I verified this on Firefox and Chrome (though on Chrome for Mac it supports Cmd+Click but not middle-click), "

Comment: Triple finger tap works on a Mac

Comment: Not sure how you manage to have a mouse that accepts both triple-finger tap AND has a middle button. But anyway, you've got the best part of an answer there is. Had you put more info in your question, we'd have got there a lot faster.

Comment: Well the triple tap is the same as middle click inside of my head.

Comment: That's the thing about asking a question… no-one knows what is not written down.